# How do I shutdown all Virtualbox VMs at once?

Tags: macos, command-line, vagrant, virtualbox

On MacOSX, from the CLI, I'd like to shutdown all VirtualBox VMs as I've started so many from various Vagrant / Test Kitchen processes.

Answer (score 5):

```
for i in `vboxmanage list runningvms | awk '{print $1}' \
| sed 's/"//g'`; do vboxmanage controlvm $i poweroff; done
```

Comment: It's usually better if you include an explanation of what your code does and why it solve the problem.